# Button closing the app instead of switching activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to make a game Tic-Tac-Toe using android studio. When I try to switch from MainActivity to another activity(Game), instead of switching, the button closes the app. I have added several buttons in Game activity but have not used them and android studio is not showing any error about that so is the problem in Game activity or MainActivity? And how to solve this problem.
Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        Button quit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.quit);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGame();
            }
        });
        quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quitGame();
            }
        });
    }
    void openGame() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    void quitGame() {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Game Activity:

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        final ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.bg);
        constraintLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                String color1[] = {"#fb5959", "#fe7738", "#f3980b", "#DBD100", "#A8D700", "#87E50C"};
                String color2[] = {"#54F370", "#00FFBC", "#00FFFF", "#00FFE9", "#00C8FF", "#0085FF"};
                Random random = new Random();
                GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BL_TR,
                    new int[]{Color.parseColor(color1[random.nextInt(6)]),Color.parseColor(color2[random.nextInt(6)])});
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);
                return false;
            }
        });
        Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        Button four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        Button five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        Button six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        Button seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        Button eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        Button nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
05/05 13:14:41: Launching 'app' on OnePlus ONE A2003.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.tictactoe/com.example.tictactoe.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 21369 on device 'oneplus-one_a2003-3222ee10'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
D/AppTracker: App Event: start
E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tictactoe, PID: 21369
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tictactoe/com.example.tictactoe.Game}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class Button
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.tictactoe.Game.onCreate(Game.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class Button
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.tictactoe.Game.onCreate(Game.java:20) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10101e6 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:867)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3964)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:680)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:72)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:192)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:111)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.tictactoe.Game.onCreate(Game.java:20) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21369 SIG: 9
```

Game Activity Xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0D95DF"
    tools:context=".Game">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.015"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.029" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.034" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.034" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.015"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.015"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.975" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.975" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.975" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player 1 (X) :"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.177"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.098" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.513"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.088" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player 2 (O) :"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.175"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.177" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.513"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="462dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="358dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vertical1"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="282dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vertical2"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="282dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontal1"
        android:layout_width="282dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontal2"
        android:layout_width="282dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.666" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post the crash stack trace

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I posted stack trace but i don't understand it. Help me please.

Comment: can you share your Game activity xml code, problem is there it seems.

Comment: Do you use AndroidX libs or just Android?

Comment: I am using Android @Lazy.

Comment: @DipankarBaghel, I have added Xml code. It contains 9 buttons for tic-tac-toe which and  2 edit text for player names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have is an inflation exception, Android is unable to inflate Button because it does not recognize an ?attr/... i had a similar problem a while back. Try removing this line in xml.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectable"
```

if problem persists remove all lines with.

```
android:.......="?attr/...."
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But I have a question that is it possible to keep button's background transparent with touch-change in layout background?

Comment: yes it is possible using alpha. Just set the alpha of the button to 0f at start. Then set it to 1f when the view is Touched.

Comment: if the answer solved your question.. please mark it as the recommended answer